# Dynamically command text into Reporting Services

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

I have a problem with a query in a report created by SQL Server Reporting Services and Visual Studio .NET.

I have a field of type string that sometimes in the database can be NULL and prevents me from making a simple search using LIKE '%%'. My idea would be to insert a clause in the `CommandText` IIF report so that if that field is NULL, actually I assigned as the default value '%', is not carried out any research that would otherwise be added to the list of the fields searched by LIKE.

The field is `Parameters.NOTE` and the `IIF` clause I thought would use:

```
IIF (Trim (Parameters! NOTE.Value) = "%", "", "AND AD.NOTE ILIKE%" + Parameters! NOTE.Value + "% ").
```

The main problem is that the report does not give me any error but even I returns no value. I can not understand how to do.

```
 <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>
SELECT
    ANG.Cognome || ' ' || ANG.Nome AS NomeDipendente,
    R.Descrizione AS Reparto,
    AD.Anno,
    AD.Mese,
    AD.DataInserimento,
    TP.Descrizione AS TipoPagamento, 
    AD.Importo,
    AD.Note, 
    getRetribuzioneDipendente(AD.Dipendente, AD.Mese, AD.Anno) AS Retribuzione, 
    (SELECT 
      SUM(AD1.Importo) 
     FROM 
      AccontiDipendenti AD1 
     WHERE 
      AD1.Dipendente = AD.Dipendente AND
      AD1.Mese = AD.Mese AND
      AD1.Anno = AD.Anno AND
      AD1.DataInserimento &lt;= AD.DataInserimento
    ) 
    AS Acconti,
    U.NickName
  FROM
    AccontiDipendenti AD
  INNER JOIN
    AnagraficaDipendenti ANG ON (AD.Dipendente = ANG.CodiceDipendente)
  INNER JOIN
    MansioniDipendenti MD ON (ANG.CodiceMansione = MD.CodiceMansione)
  INNER JOIN
    Reparti R ON (MD.CodiceReparto = R.CodiceReparto)
  INNER JOIN
    Utenti U ON (AD.UserName = U.UserName) 
  INNER JOIN
    TipiPagamento TP ON (AD.CodiceTipoPag = TP.CodiceTipoPag)
  WHERE 
 ANG.CodiceDipendente ILIKE COALESCE(@CODICEDIPENDENTE, '%') AND
    R.CodiceReparto ILIKE COALESCE(@CODICEREPARTO, '%') AND 
    AD.CodiceTipoPag ILIKE COALESCE(@CODICETIPOPAG, '%') AND 
    to_date(to_char(AD.DataInserimento, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') &gt;= to_date(@INIZIO, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND
    to_date(to_char(AD.DataInserimento, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') &lt;=   to_date(@FINE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                IIF(Trim(Parameters!NOTE.Value)="%", "" , " AND AD.NOTE ILIKE %" + Parameters!NOTE.Value  + "%")
</CommandText>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="NOTEASSEGNO">
            <Value>=IIF(Trim(Parameters!NOTE.Value)="%", "%" , "%" + Parameters!NOTE.Value  + "%")</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="CODICEDIPENDENTE">
            <Value>=Parameters!CODICEDIPENDENTE.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="CODICEREPARTO">
            <Value>=Parameters!CODICEREPARTO.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="INIZIO">
            <Value>=Parameters!DATAINIZIO.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="FINE">
            <Value>=Parameters!DATAFINE.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="CODICETIPOPAG">
            <Value>=Parameters!CODICETIPOPAG.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
      </Query>
```

Comment: SO you want to apply the Like on column but if its is null then Like is not operating write ?

Comment: Yes a want to do a search with this column. But if a user does not fill the form NOTE i don't want to include note into my search. There is a way to create a command text dinamically? Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter to pass to the query.Suppose the parameter name is `@Note`. Set the `@Note` value to the `Parameters!NOTE.Value`. And make sure you make both the parameter in Report and in the query at both places `Null` by dfault. You can do the condition like,

```
 AND (@Note IS NULL OR AD.NOTE LIKE +'%'@Note+'%')
```

This will first check that if the @Note value is null if null then it will not go for next filter if not null then it will go for the filter of `Like`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try this solution and tell you the response

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the previous comment because i have tried without clause @Note IS NULL and it still doesn't work. Now it works. I've put this one into command text:   AND (@NOTE IS NULL OR AD.NOTE  ILIKE  COALESCE(@NOTE, '%') ) and this one into QueryParameters: 
          <QueryParameter Name="NOTE">
            <Value>="%"+Parameters!NOTE.Value+"%"</Value>
          </QueryParameter>. Best and thanks a lot